# Nginx filter module installation

Tags: nginx

I am working on a nginx filter module. I could successfully install my module by following this - http://www.evanmiller.org/nginx-modules-guide.html tutorial. But it seems that all the other filter modules are not called now except the one which I have added. How can I debug this ?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a long time since the question was asked, but after spending quite a bit of time on this, here is the issue:

In the `config` file of your module, you need to provide this line:

```
HTTP_AUX_FILTER_MODULES="$HTTP_AUX_FILTER_MODULES your_module_name"
```

And you can remove the `HTTP_MODULES` line if you only have a filter.

Answer (score -1):

before

1. `ps awx | grep nginx`  to check nginx process id
2. Stop Nginx server

```bsh
gdb <path>  // may be ->sr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx
(gdb) set-follow-fork-mode child         
set detach-on-fork  off               
set logging on                           
set confirm off                         
rbreak ngx_http*  // you want to break point ..                       
run
```